# How to connect Surface Pro 6 to Apple Thunderbolt Display 27"

Tags: video-adapter

I want to connect a Surface Pro 6 to an Apple Thunderbolt Display 27".

What do I need to do to transfer display signals to the Apple Display?

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, you can't connect Surface Pro to Apple Thunderbolt Display as @jksoegaard suggested because Thunderbolt Display can be connected to thunderbolt port only. Trust me, I have both, I've tried, it's not working and it makes sense it doesn't. When Surface Pro comes equipped with thunderbolt port instead of miniDisplay Port, it should be possible, but right now, it is not.

Comment: Welcome to Ask Different! Please refrain from adding comments in the Answer section, this is for answers to the questions. Once you have sufficient [reputation](http://apple.stackexchange.com/help/whats-reputation) you’ll be able to add [comments](http://apple.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/comment) and ask follow-up questions. To gain reputation, [answer questions that are clear and concise](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead).   - From Review

Answer (score 0):

You just need to plugin the monitor to the Surface Pro 6.

The monitor comes with with a combination cable of both Thunderbolt (i.e. mini-DisplayPort connector) and MagSafe for charging. Just take the Thunderbolt-cable and plug it straight into the Surface Pro 6.

The Surface Pro 6 has a mini-DisplayPort for display output, and it is compatible with the Thunderbolt cable from the monitor for transferring the display signal. Note that you will not get other features working over this cable such as speakers or camera.